# main menu page redirects to user ID

Tags: php, functions, users, id

I have a site that displays fitness results to clients. It works by showing them a page based on their UID displaying unique charts and graphs etc.

I can redirect members to the unique pages on login, but I can't seem to add a menu item that also redirects them.

I need the menu item because currently, when clients log in and view their unique page; if they leave that page there's no navigation back to it.

Any ideas? Is this possible?

I'm a novice with code but I am learning, so please bear that in mind!

Cheers

Comment: Anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a page with a page template that gets all info based on the user ID. Then you can add that page to the menu.
Something like this:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: User Info
 */
 get_header();

 //Your code for getting the users id
 $user_id = '123';

 //Output userinfo using your code
 ...
```

This code shold be saved as a file in your theme folder. Name it something like `template-user.php`. Then when you create a new page in WordPress you can select this template as the page template.

To get your theme´s HTML structure easily, you can copy the content of your theme `page.php` and add it to this file.

Comment: That sounds great. Thanks for getting back to me. Where would I place that code?

Comment: Updated the answer with more info about that.

Comment: Sounds great I'll give it a try today, thanks so much for taking the time the help, really appreciated

Comment: Great. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.